# jQuery tabs - using appendTo to add or remove tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm trying to append a tab to a div receiver, when the close button is pressed

Any ideas?

Comment: When which close button is pressed? Can you please explain your question in more detail?

Comment: Can you post some code from your attempts to do this?   We will need something to work from.

Comment: -1 for incredibly unclear question - you can't really expect people to answer when comments for clarification like this one is longer than the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* add a tab dynamically.
Ty this in console at http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs

```
$("#tabs").tabs("add", "#tabs-4", "Tab 4", 4);
$("#tabs > div:eq(3)").html("<b>New Tab</b>");
```